# ModuleNotFoundError: No module name selenium

Tags: selenium, pip

When I try to run an automation.py code that I created in python using Selenium I get the error message ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'. I have tried to run the pip install. I am using python version 3.

> pip3 install selenium

But I still get the error message.

Comment: Are you sure that python version that you use to run Selenium script is exactly the same as the version of python of pip3?

Comment: what code editor do you use?for pycharm you might not added Python Interpreter. Try to add your Python Interpreter in settings like.
File -> Settings -> Projects -> Python Interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install selenium-webdriver
```